# How to set condition in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help here. I dont know what is the problem but the 1st modal is popping up while the 2nd one is not.

My program works like this.

1. Both of my modal should be clickable after it was close but when it open again the checkbox checked should retain like my first modal.
2. What i want to do on my 2nd modal is that I want it to behave like
   radio button, meaning I can only choose 1 checkbox and it will
   retain its value when i reopen it again.

Please check also my working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fe73awsu/10/

Here is my code:
**test.php**

```
    <form method="post" name="testform" action="">

    <a href="#modal"> <!-- when the input textbox was clicked, modal will pop up -->
        Label 1<input readonly type="text" name="txt1" placeholder="inputTest">     
    </a>

  <br><br>

  <a href="#moda2"> <!-- when the input textbox was clicked, modal will pop up -->
        Label 2<input readonly type="text" name="txt2" placeholder="inputTest">     
    </a>

<!-- modal starts here -->
    <div class="modalwrapper" id="modal">   <!-- modal -->
            <div class="modalcontainer">    
                <div class="modalcol1">
                    <label>Test 1</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="test_modal[]" value="1">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Test 2</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="test_modal[]" value="2">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Test 3</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="test_modal[]" value="3">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Test 4</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="test_modal[]" value="4">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Test 5</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="test_modal[]" value="5">
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="savebutton">
                        <button class="btn1" type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- close modalcol1 -->
            </div> <!-- close modalcontainer -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div> <!-- close modalwrapper -->


    <div class="modalwrapper" id="modal2">   <!-- modal -->
            <div class="modalcontainer">    
                <div class="modalcol1">
                    <label>Mango</label>
                    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="fruit1" value="1">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Banna</label>
                    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="fruit2" value="2">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Grapes</label>
                    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="fruit3" value="3">
                    <div class="clear"></div>               
                    <div class="savebutton">
                    <button class="btn1" type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- close modalcol1 -->
            </div> <!-- close modalcontainer -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div> <!-- close modalwrapper -->
</form>
```

my **javascript**

```
 $(document).on("click","input[name='txt1']", function()
{
    $('#modal').show();
});

$(document).on("click","input[name='txt2']", function()
{
    $('#modal2').show();
});

$(document).on("click",".btn1", function(){
   $('#modal').hide();
});

$(".radio").change(function() {
        $(".radio").prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
```

Please check also my working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fe73awsu/10/

Can u also clean my codes?

Comment: You have a TYPO. It should be `$('#moda2').show();`, see https://jsfiddle.net/5fdn2jaa/

Comment: @Satpal hey, i updated my jsfiddle and my post. please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each modal must have a unique id and Each link can refer to a unique modal-id.

```
...
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-     labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
...
<a href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
...
```

Your code had issue with ID's for modal window as well buttons to close it.
I have fixed it here : https://jsfiddle.net/raviroshan/g77ngpat/1/

Comment: hey mate, where is the part that you edit? i cant see it but it is working fine now. can u tell it to me here or just comment on the fiddle. one more thing, can you edit my javascript with same concept, i think mine is a bit messy.

Comment: oh now i saw it. you assign each id for it, thanks bro! can u fix my javascript by the way with the same concept? it is messy :D

Comment: @NiCeMaRK: If it's working for you, then you can mark the Answer as Accepted/Upvote. 

I just made few change in HTML - Unique IDs for both the Modals, Unique class for Button inside Modal, and in JS - Hiding the modal on btn2 click.

You can compare the complete changes with your version @ https://jsfiddle.net/raviroshan/g77ngpat/1/

Comment: very great! now i understand that i should assign ids for every modal. thank mate!

Comment: hey sir, still there? have a problem now with this model. how am i going to remove the #modalname on the url , because when i refresh it keeps popping up because of the url extension of it. how am i gonna remove it there?

Comment: So, basically if ur modal window is open and you refresh, you don't wanna show modal ? Then just don't put the #modalname in URL or, alter the page URL on page load using JavaScript

Comment: Cool buddy... Nice to know.. (y)